# Sublime Text 3, rbenv, rspec, spring & ruby-tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring, rspec, rbenv, ruby-test

I'm using the excellent plugin [sublime-text-2-ruby-tests](https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests) with Sublime Text 3 and have it working. However, the tests are relatively slow (about 5-6 seconds for a single test and 10 seconds for a full spec test).

I've noticed that when I go to the command line and type `rspec` it's pretty slow (about 8 seconds) but if I type `spring rspec` it's faster at about 4 seconds.

I'm trying my best to figure out how to use spring with ruby-tests but can't get it working at all. I've tried both the answers given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669651/sublime-text-3-rbenv-testunit-rubytest-and-spring-correct-configuation-to-get) question but the tests are still slow.

Anyone any idea how to get ruby-tests to use Spring in Sublime Text?

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1):

And just as I post the question I figure out the solution.

Just needed to add the following to RubyTest.sublime-settings

```
{
  "check_for_rbenv": true,
  "check_for_spring": true,
}
```

Carry on!

My god the difference in speed is something else.